# Need example of extjs6 desktop javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs, web-applications, extjs6

I need to upgrade from Extjs3 to Extjs6(GPL).  I have a desktop app with several smaller desktop apps.  I'm pretty sure I can figure it all out once I get the version 6 Desktop stood-up.   Does anybody have a bare-bones example of standing up the desktop witha a wallpaper in javascript without using sencha command or the bootloader etc.   I just need to see the Javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: This will be worst upgrade i never seen. App should be upgrade to one level from current version. I think if you try to upgrade from 3 to 6, Sure you will face lot of build issue and you dont require MVVM also because already your app in MVC. So there is no point in upgrading. Think before you start.

Answer (score 0):

Jumping from v3 straight into v6.5 myself over the last couple of weeks, with quite a few years in between, I have faced the same challenge.

My advice is to just get stuck in to Sencha CMD and the MVC/MVVM layout because neither of them are going away soon.

You can stick with the flat v3 layout if you want, but it makes much more sense to use the tools on offer and spend a little bit of time figuring those out rather than resisting the change only to face it later.

I started off with the tutorial on the Sencha site on how to create your first app using CMD - this can be used to create the bare-bones example for you:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/guides/getting_started/getting_started.html

From there you should have enough knowledge and resources in the examples/documentation to build out what you need.

For what it's worth, Sencha CMD is a great tool to build a leaner, more compact javascript output than if you include the entire library, so it actually works in your favour.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Since posting this I have gone back and basically learnded the basics for CMD.  In the end, I still went back to the flat layout as bloated as it may be.  Seems much easier to debug and add test code on the running test bed with individual JS files.  I have also managed to get the desktop up and running.  I may go back to command at some point...

Comment: Well at least you're up and running! I've been suffering from a few knowledge gaps with CMD but there's plenty of info out there on it to help with the most common issues.